# Python returns string instead of list during iterate

Tags: python, string, list

I have encountered this most unexpected behaviour which I cannot seem to explain. I have written a Python function to parse a PDB file (atom coordinates for protein structure) as as a list of lists, e.g.:

```
[
['ATOM  ', ' 1700', '  N  ', ' ', 'VAL', ' B', '  11', ' ', '   ', matrix([[-19.164, -27.781, -11.31 ]]), '  1.00', ' 18.57', '      ', '    ', ' N', '  '],
...
]
```

When I iterate over the list as follows:

```
for line in pdb[:50]:
    print line, len(line), type(line)
```

I get each element as expected, having 16 elements in each list.

However, if I run the following:

```
for line in pdb:
    print line, len(line), type(line)
```

The 6th line (numbering at 0), is a string of value `' 311'`. This also occurs if I use `enumerate()` to iterate over `pdub`. If I extract this element manually using `pdb[6]`, it is a normal list with 16 elements and the value `' 311'` appears nowhere in this list.

This makes absolutely no sense to me whatsoever!

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me either. Can you try providing a [mcve]?

Comment: You should give us details/code about your parsing function you wrote

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Looks to me it is a side effect of slicing your list.

Comment: It is Python 2.7. In preparing the example, I found the problem! The loop had some other lines, the last line being `pdb[6] = new_value` instead of `pdb[i][6] = new_value`. So, it was modifying the entire list, not its 6th element, so it was always on the 6th line it would fail. I've been banging my head on this for a good hour, and couldn't quite understand the problem -__-. Thanks for all the help so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note: Only true in Python3.X

The main difference between `for i in l[1:]` (or `for i in list(l)`, as long as slicing is not lazy) and `for i in l` is if `l` is a generator, the first one will process the whole generator into a list and then sending it to `for`, when the second one will process one element of `l` at the time:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool
from random import randint
class Gen:
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.__l = limit
        self.__t = []
        self.__v = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.__v += 1
        if self.__v +1 >= self.__l:
            raise StopIteration
        print("NEXT:{}".format(self.__v))
        sleep(0.01)
        w = 0
        self.__t.append(self.__v)
        return self.__t[:]

r = Gen(1000)
```

So

```
for i in r:
    sleep(0.2)
    print("--->R:{}".format(i[-1]))

>>> NEXT:1
--->R:1
NEXT:2
--->R:2
NEXT:3
--->R:3
NEXT:4
--->R:4
NEXT:5
...
```

And

```
for i in list(r):
    sleep(0.2)
    print("--->R:{}".format(i[0]))

>>> NEXT:1
NEXT:2
NEXT:3 
NEXT:4
NEXT:5
...
--->R:1
--->R:2
--->R:3
--->R:4
...
```